# Problems meet when developing screen capture program under Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, layout, coordinates

I'm developing a simple screen capture program under Mac OS, I set the main window to be transparent, and use a NSBox instance contained in main window to specify the area to be captured, here are the significant code and main interface of my program(sorry, no reputation to public image):

```
capturedImage = CGDisplayCreateImage( kCGDirectMainDisplay );//capture the whole screen

NSRect boxRect = [mBox borderRect];//mBox is an instance of NSBox, lies in main window

capturedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(capturedImage, boxRect);//obtain an image specified by mBox
```

I cannot get the right image as I want, I know there may be something wrong with the coordinates but I cannot figure it out, can someone help me with this?
another one, there are 3 buttons on the main window, I want them fixed on the right bottom of main window as I drag and resize the main window, but I have no idea about the layout schema of Interface Builder, is there any good solution? better be real useful code with comments. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [read up about coordinate systems.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html) Your `NSBox` instance is a view, and asking for its `borderRect` will return a rect in window coordinates.

You need the rectangle to be in the screen coordinate system, because your whole screen image uses that coordinate system. You can use this method to convert the rect:

```
NSRect screenBoxRect = [[mBox window] convertRectToScreen:[mBox frame]];
```